# how to add dependencies to $componentController in angular 1.5 while unit testing

Tags: angularjs, testing, dependencies, components

I want to add dependencies to my Controller in a component:

Here is my component:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .component('myComponent', {
    template: '<div>some content</div>',
    controller: ["$routeParams", function ($routeParams) {
       var ctrl = this;
       ctrl.myId = $routeParams.id;
  });
```

Now I just want to test this as follow:

```
describe("spec for myComponent", function () {

  var $componentController;
  var $routeParams;

  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(inject(function (_$componentController_, _$routeParams_) {
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
    $routeParams = _$routeParams_;
    $routeParams = {
      myId: 42
    }
  }));

  it('should init', function () {

    var ctrl = $componentController('myComponent', $routeParams, null);

    expect(ctrl.myId).toBe(42);

  });
});
```

But unfortunately **ctrl.myId is undefined** because $routeParams are not correctly injected. Why?

Comment: change `var ctrl = $componentController('myComponent', $routeParams, null);` to `var ctrl = $componentController('myComponent', {$routeParams}, null);` Also note, you can use the second argument to inject a mock $routeParams (see Neo182's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had very similar situation as yours, googled for a while but found almost nothing, but at last I solved the problem myself : Here is the solution for your case:

```
describe("spec for myComponent", function () {

  var $componentController;
  var mockRouteParams = {id : 1};

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$componentController_) {
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
  }));

  it('should init', function () {

    var ctrl = $componentController('myComponent', {$routeParams:mockRouteParams}, null);

    expect(ctrl.myId).toBe(1);

  });
});
```

Also check [Mocking $routeParams in a test in order to change its attributes dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720241/mocking-routeparams-in-a-test-in-order-to-change-its-attributes-dynamically) regarding mocking of $routeParams.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be re-defining `$routeParams` here:

```
$routeParams = _$routeParams_;
$routeParams = {
  myId: 42
}
```

Doing the following should solve your problem (also note that you expect `id` to be and attribute of `$routeParams`, not `myId`):

```
$routeParams = _$routeParams_;
$routeParams.id = 42;
```